# Is there any way to disable the *Alexa cards* from AWS lambda (Node JS)?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-lambda-edge

I have not enabled display interface, not using renderer template, not using Alexa presentation language but still I am getting Alexa card in FireTV cube whenever I invoke any intent in my custom skill.
Is there any API available in response builder to disable this Alexa card?

Answer (score 0):

That's a default behavior of alexa devices with screen as mentioned here [default cards](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/display-and-behavior-specifications-for-alexa-enabled-devices-with-a-screen.html#graphical-features)

So these cards can't be disabled.